# How to Unscale Response variable in a Test set

Tags: r, scale

i built a model on training dataset which was scaled . I then used predict() function on the validation dataset which doesnt have the response variable to predict the response variable . 
Now , i need to convert the predicted values to normal scale (Descale them). How can i do this.

For the training set , i did the following.

```
target_mean <- mean(TrainData$actual_y)
target_sd <- sd(TrainData$actual_y)
TrainData$predicted_y_unscaled <- TrainData$predicted_y*target_sd + target_mean
```

But for the test set , i dont have the actual_y value to calculate the target_mean , target_sd as above. How can i proceed in this case ?

Comment: You can check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209784/rescale-predictions-of-regression-model-fitted-on-scaled-predictors)

Comment: As akrun links to. The idea is simple. In your test dataset you would scale it according to the training dataset. As such if scaled correctly, the standard deviation and mean from the training data should be used on the test data for unscaling.